# How does periodic steady state analysis find the transfer function of switched capacitor circuits?

Tags: simulation, switched-capacitor

The paper linked below suggests that periodic steady state (PSS) analysis is a way to find the transfer function of switched capacitor (SC) circuits.

https://designers-guide.org/analysis/sc-filters.pdf

Can someone explain to me how this works?

In my limited understanding, PSS analysis first applies a large signal (i.e. clock) to a circuit, linearizes it at several time steps within a clock period, and then does a small signal analysis at every time step.

If that's how it works, I don't understand how that could get you the discrete time transfer function of an SC circuit.

For example, consider the two circuits shown below. These circuits work with 2 clock phases, "1" and "2"—the number next to a switch indicates when it is closed. The top circuit is an SC integrator and the bottom circuit is an SC amplifier—their transfer functions are very different.

How could you tell the difference if you were looking at a linearized circuit in each time step? Both the integrator and amplifier have the same linearized circuit at each time step.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdXduc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBgBp8.png)</sup>

Comment: You seem to be both wanting an explanation of the paper and an analysis of this very simple circuit. I suggest you choose one or the other. Why does one of the switches have a label 2/closed?

Comment: @Andyaka I only want an explanation of the paper. I am using the circuit to illustrate what I don’t understand about the paper. I’ll get rid of the confusing label.

Comment: What is your primary goal? (1) To find and display the transfer function of an SC-circuit or (2) To understand the specific method as described by Kundert in the linked paper? I ask this question because I know about two other methods which make use of analog (time continuous) models for simulating the frequency response of such time discrete circuits.

Comment: @LvW my primary goal is to find and understand the best way to simulate the transfer function of an SC circuit. It seems like PSS is the recommended method based on the linked paper and various lecture notes posted online.

Comment: @David I cannot agree. As far as I can see the method as proposed by Kundert applies to the program SPECTRE only (or was implemented in SPECTRE). I do not think that it can be used in other simulation programs without specific modifications.. I repeat again: There are two other methods which make use of analog continuous models for simulating SC circuits in the frequency domain.

Comment: @LvW PSS is available in other  simulators in addition to SPECTRE. For example, we have EldoRF at my company which can do all of the periodic analyses (e.g. PSS, PAC, PXF). The idea that RF analyses apply to SC circuits roughly makes sense to me. I can see the similarity between the LO and RF in mixers and the clock and signal in SC circuits. I just don't understand the details.

Comment: @LvW actually, my description of how I think PSS works in the question could be identical to your controlled sources method. The linearized circuits in PSS may be stimulated by controlled sources which capture the scaling and delay like in your example.

Comment: @DavidG25 Thank you for this information.  My present understanding is that PSS cannot be run with general-purpose simulators like PSpice, LTSpice etc.  Is this correct?

Comment: @LvW I don't think LTspice has it. It seems like it's usually part of an RF analysis package.

Comment: Yes - this is also my present knowledge.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question: "*How does periodic steady state analysis find the transfer function of switched capacitor circuits*?"

As to my knowledge, there are two methods which allow an analysis of SC circuits in the frequency domain using general purpose simulation prorams.

**(1)** Separate simulation of the two clock phases with subsequent coupling via controlled sources. This method is described in

Biolek D., Biolkova V., Kolka Z.: *"AC analysis of idealized SC circuits in SPICE-compatible Programs"* (Proc. 11th WSEAS int. conf. on circuts, Kreta 2007, pp 223-227).

A **short description** of the method is shown **below** (it was prepared by myself).

**(2)** Use of an artificially generated component ("Storistor"), which represents a resistor with storage/delay properties. This method is described in:

Nelin, B.D.: *"Analysis of SC networks using General-Purpose Simulation Programs"*, IEEE Trans. Circuit and systems, vol CAS-30, 1983, pp 43-48.

[image]